# how to show gridview android this code

Tags: android, gridview

1. > new HttpAsyncTask().execute(Url);

   ```
   public static String GET(String url){
   InputStream inputStream = null;
   String result = "";
   try {

       // create HttpClient
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       // make GET request to the given URL
       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

       // receive response as inputStream
       inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

       // convert inputstream to string
       if(inputStream != null)
           result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
       else
           result = "Did not work!";

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }

    return result;
   }

     private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
   String line = "";
   String result = "";
   while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
       result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

   }
   ---------------------------------------------------------------

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
               URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
               DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                       .newInstance();
               DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
               // Download the XML file
               Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
               doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
               // Locate the Tag Name
               System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
               nodelist  = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");


               System.out.println("Number of row nodes: " + nodelist.getLength());

               for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) 
               {   Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);

                   if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nodelist.item(temp);
                   nodelist  = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");


                   String urunName = eElement.getAttribute("urunismi");
                   System.out.println("Ürünismi: " + urunName);
                   String fiyat = eElement.getAttribute("tlfiyat");
                   System.out.println("fiyat: " + urunName);
                   String gurup = eElement.getAttribute("grupisim");
                   System.out.println("gurup: " + urunName);

                       System.out.println("-----------------------");

               }}

           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       return GET(urls[0]);
            }
   // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nodelist.item(temp);
        builder.append(" " +  eElement.getAttribute("urunismi"));
        builder.append(" " +  eElement.getAttribute("tlfiyat"));
        builder.append(" " +  eElement.getAttribute("grupisim"));

        builder.append("\n");
        }
        textview.setText(builder.append(result));


    }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please be descriptive about your problem. One cannot help with the ambiguous title you have provided.

Comment: I dont know to use gridview . but ı want to show thıs code output grıdvıew

Comment: thıs code shows only android xml file output list